# Filter list in a WebPart by Contains not Equals (adding a wildcard)

Tags: 2010, filter, data-view-web-part

If I need to "search" list data using a wildcard, I have to modify the XSL code.
A step-by-step instruction for doing it in SP2007 has been provided at [Can I Filter a List/Data View using Contains instead of equals in SP2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/23519/17591) (in a link-only answer to [Phil Wicklund's old blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20130821001648/http://blog.philwicklund.com/fff/2009/04/using-the-data-view-web-part-to-search-a-sharepoint-list.html)).

I just tried to implement Phil's tips and got to point 3 of his instructions, where I got stuck.
All the previous steps could be applied to SP2010 with minor changes from the SP2007 version he refers to, but starting from this one I could not adapt Phil's tips for 2010 version:

> 3. Lastly we need to edit the rows query that the Data View uses. In the Code view, search for `name="Rows"`. Notice the select on that variable contains a query – this is what we need to modify. By default it brings back all rows, but we need filter out the rows that do not match our search term.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add hidden calculated fields to the list that helps you out with the searching and filtering.

Reference: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/09/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-does-not-begin-with-filtered-list-view/